# Positioning a JLabel in the center of a panel and a JLabel to the right of the same panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, alignment

I have a `JPanel`  and inside it are two `JLabel` components: `headerLabel` and `timeLabel`

The problem is that I'm having trouble making `headerLabel` sit in the center of the panel and `timeLabel` sit to the far right. I have tried several different Layout Managers (`GridBagLayout`, `BorderLayout` etc.) and techniques (`Box.createHorizontalStrut(X)`, adding `Insets`) and they all either end up pushing `headerLabel` to the far left and `timeLabel` to the far right or placing them both in the center.

Below is a graphical representation of how I want it to look:

[image]

Is there a particular Layout Manager I should be using to get this result?

Comment: .setLayout(null);  You can use a null layout and set the bounds to the labels manually. headerlabel.setBounds(1, 2, 3, 4); But I would not go with this approach, unless it is a fixed frame

Comment: @Rat2000 Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. This is a simple requirement and there is no need to even think about a null layout.

Comment: @camickr that is why I left a comment and not an answer. cause it is not an answer but just a "fast fix" for him. Judging by the profile, this is just a university assignment, witch I am sure he just wants to finish it, given the fact that he didn't research a bit until he posted the answer(you can find a lot of examples online). but indeed, the answer gave by you should fix his problem.

Comment: I actually did do about an hour of research but couldn't find the exact answer to my specific problem. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: @Rat2000, it is not a fast fix. It will cause other problems like when you attempt to use pack() on the frame. Using a layout manager properly will be the `fast fix`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have tried several different Layout Managers (GridBagLayout, BorderLayout etc.)

Well, post your code. We can't guess what you might be doing.

I would use a `BorderLayout`.

Add one label to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` and the other to the `BorderLayouyt.LINE_END`.

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() ):

JLabel center = new JLabel("CENTER");
center.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER); // maybe you are missing this
add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

JLabel right = new JLabel("RIGHT");
add(right, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Which tell the text how to align itself when there is extra horizontal space.

Comment: Thank you, this worked a charm! I was missing the line you specified I might be missing. This also allowed me to add a component to the left too, by adding another:
`JLabel left = new JLabel("LEFT");
add(left, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get there with GridBagLayout.

headerPanel will sit at 0,0 with FILL_BOTH, centered and fillx = 1.0

timePanel will sit at 0,1 and no further fill options.

Now the display for those will largely depend on big your original panel is rendered. If it is inside a JDialog or any other container that's `pack()`ed, all they will still appear "side by side" as this is the best way to layout those elements.

If this still bugs you, you could assign minimum & preferred size to headerPanel so that packing will not shrink it below that size.

```
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel lblHeader = new JLabel("HEADER");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblHeader = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblHeader.weightx = 1.0;
    gbc_lblHeader.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblHeader.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblHeader.gridy = 0;
    add(lblHeader, gbc_lblHeader);

    JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("TIME");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTime = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblTime.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblTime.gridy = 0;
    add(lblTime, gbc_lblTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - this particular way gave me more control over the labels but the simpler answer provided by @camickr is all I needed. I will bear your answer in mind if I do need more control of my components in future.

Comment: Thx. Now you have enough reputation to upvote answers you like but are not "your" solution. (hint ;-) )